# Joomla loosing custom session variables and cookies?

Tags: php, cookies, joomla, session-variables

I created a login page outside of Joomla to use with certain pages that require a login/password protection. It checks to see if the user is already logged in, and if not saves the page they're on to a session variable ($redirected_from) and redirects to the login page. Then when they're logged in it saves their logged in state to another session variable ($username), so if they browse around and come back to one of the pages that requires a login, it doesn't redirect them to the login page again.

This is all working fine to a point. You can use the menu on the left for that section of the site and go between pages and back, and it remembers the logged in state. The problem is if you click on the Home link and go to the homepage, then go back to that section of the site, it forgets that you've logged in and you're redirected to the login page again.

I tried creating cookies to save the values too, figuring that Joomla was doing something to delete/reset the session variables when you visited "Home" and I have it echo the value onto the page. It saves the logged in state until you visit "Home" and then it's gone (echo's out nothing).

Is there something that Joomla does on the homepage that's going to reset any custom variables (session or cookie), and if so, is there any kind of work around for this?

Here's how the variables are being saved on the login page:

```
if ($username == $preset_username && $password == $preset_password) {
        $session =& JFactory::getSession();
        $session->set('user', $username);     

        if(!isset($_COOKIE['user']) || $_COOKIE['user'] == '') {
            setcookie('user', $username);
            JRequest::setVar('user', $username, 'COOKIE');
            $_COOKIE['user'] = $username;
        }
}
```

And here's how every page is checking for the user (using an include):

```
if (!($session->get('user'))) {
        $session->set('user', "");
}

$user_cookie = $_COOKIE['user'];

if (($session->get('user') == "" || $session->get('user') == null) && (!isset($_COOKIE['user']) || $_COOKIE['user'] == '')) {

    ...check against list of pages requiring login and if match saves page and redirects (this part works)...

}
```

Comment: I'm kind of confused because Joomla already has a username and logged in status (the $guest property) and it always checks any user against the permissions for a page. Why would you need a list of pages requiring login? That is determined by the access level of the content of the page.

Comment: I'm somewhat new to customizing Joomla, to be honest. But essentially there are a few sections of the site, and in two of the sections there needs to be password protection on some of the pages. The login required for the protected pages in one section is different from pages in the other section. And my client wants it to be possible to be logged into one or the other or both.

Comment: Are these things that are not in joomla?  It really sounds like you need to read the documentation about how to use ACL.  Make different user groups for each of the separate areas. Create an access level for each group. Change the access level for the different pages to match the one for the group you created. No customization required to do this, this is why you use a CMS because things like ACL are ready to go.